# Combining duplicate records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that holds a list of parts, location of the parts and the quantity on hand. The problem I have is someone put a space in front of the location when they added it to the database. This allowed there to be two records.

I need to create a job that will find the parts with spaces before the location and add those parts to the identical parts without spaces in front of the location. I'm not quite sure where to even start with this.

This is the before:

```
  Partno  |  PartRev  |  Location  |  OnHand  |  Identity_Column
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  0D6591D    000          MV3         55.000     103939
  0D6591D    000         MV3          -55.000    104618
```

This is what I would like to have after the job ran:

```
  Partno  |  PartRev  |  Location  |  OnHand  |  Identity_Column
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  0D6591D    000         MV3         0           104618
```

Comment: Is it just a single white space ? or it can be more than just a single white space

Comment: Is the "after" row Identity_Column value a mistake? If you're keeping the row without a space it should be 104618, unless something else is going on...

Comment: Sorry Chris that was a mistake

Comment: Prdp it could potentially be more than a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps: 1. update the records with the correct locations, 2. delete the records with the wrong locations.

```
update mytable
set onhand = onhand + 
(
  select coalesce(sum(wrong.onhand), 0)
  from mytable wrong
  where wrong.location like ' %'
  and trim(wrong.location) = mytable.location
)
where location not like ' %';

delete from mytable where location like ' %';
```

Comment: Duplicate keys? We are not inserting data, we are not updating keys, we are even deleting records. How can we get such an error then?

Comment: You may just want to change `trim` with `ltrim` or `rtrim` accordingly

Comment: The key is a combination of the Part, PartRev, and location by updating the location it creates a duplicate key error since those three would be exactly the same.

Comment: @TECC how does updating onHand cause duplicate key error?

Comment: Stephen you are totally correct I read the steps and not the code. I apologize for not reading your answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some grouping with a HAVING clause on to identify the records. I've used `REPLACE` to replace spaces with empty strings in the location column, you could also use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample
    (
      [Partno] VARCHAR(7) ,
      [PartRev] INT ,
      [Location] VARCHAR(5) ,
      [OnHand] INT ,
      [Identity_Column] INT
    );


INSERT INTO #Sample
    ([Partno], [PartRev], [Location], [OnHand], [Identity_Column])
VALUES
    ('0D6591D', 000, ' MV3', 55.000, 103939),
    ('0D6591D', 000, 'MV3', -55.000, 104618)
;

SELECT Partno ,
       PartRev ,
       REPLACE( Location, ' ', '') Location,
       SUM(OnHand) [OnHand]
FROM #Sample
GROUP BY REPLACE(Location, ' ', '') ,
         Partno ,
         PartRev
HAVING COUNT(Identity_Column) > 1;

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Produces:

```
Partno  PartRev Location    OnHand
0D6591D 0       MV3         0
```

Comment: I think my biggest problem is finding the bad record and finding the matching good record.