# Left outer join query is not working properly as per their condition

Tags: sql-server

I am filtering the data of more than one table by sql select query and for that I am using left outer join in c#.net. So by excuting this query filter is not working properly.

For ex : I have data whose branchid is 1 and yearid is 1. So when excute the query it works fine i.e. it shows that data only whose branch and year id is 1.

other data whose branchid is 2 and yearid is 1. So when I am excuting the query according to this filter at that time it shows branchid is 1 and yearid is 1 and also branchid is 2 and yearid is 1.

means at second time it shows whole data of branch and yearid. So at that time filter is not working.

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Client.clientname AS ClientName ,
        RetailInvoice.invoiceno AS InvoiceNo ,
        RetailInvoice.pono AS PoNO ,
        RetailInvoice.issuedate AS IssueDate ,
        RetailInvoice.duedate AS DueDate ,
        RetailInvoice.discount AS Discount ,
        RetailInvoice.shipping AS Shipping ,
        RetailInvoice.tax AS Tax ,
        RetailInvoice.vat AS Vat ,
        RetailInvoice.sese AS Sese ,
        RetailInvoice.paymenttype AS PaymentType ,
        RetailInvoice.chequeno AS Chequeno ,
        RetailInvoice.totalamt AS TotalAmt ,
        RetailInvoice.description AS Description ,
        RetailInvoice.paymentpaid AS PaymentPaid ,
        RetailInvoice.subtotal AS Subtotal ,
        RetailInvoicePayment.productid AS ProductName ,
        RetailInvoicePayment.uom AS Uom ,
        RetailInvoicePayment.quantity AS Quantity ,
        RetailInvoicePayment.price AS Price
FROM    tbl_retailinvoice RetailInvoice
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_retailinvoicepayment RetailInvoicePayment 
             ON RetailInvoice.invoiceno = RetailInvoicePayment.invoiceno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_clientdetail Client 
             ON RetailInvoice.clientid = Client.clientid
WHERE   RetailInvoice.BranchID = 1
        AND RetailInvoice.YearID = 1
        AND RetailInvoice.invoiceno = 1;
```

Comment: this doesn't really have any relevance to c# or .net, it's just a sql problem

Comment: I am not telling this is relevance to c# or not. I want to describe that I have create this in c#. So that's y I have adding the c# tag. I think you understand @Tanner that I am telling you.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this simply boils down to being a problem with the SQL in the post, so the other information doesn't add any value to the question, it's just extra noise.

Comment: noted. Thank You for the information. I will be remember at next time. So do you the solution of this problem.

Comment: If you provide some simple sample data with your expected outputIi will look at it, but I can't answer based on what you've provided. Create a simplified example, with minimal columns and rows that shows the problem using the approach I use in my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984115/combining-duplicate-records-in-sql-server/41984262#41984262

Comment: It would be worth reading both [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and get better answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

```
FROM    tbl_retailinvoice RetailInvoice
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_retailinvoicepayment RetailInvoicePayment 
             ON RetailInvoice.invoiceno = RetailInvoicePayment.invoiceno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_clientdetail Client 
             ON RetailInvoice.clientid = Client.clientid
WHERE   RetailInvoice.BranchID = 1
        AND RetailInvoice.YearID = 1
        AND RetailInvoice.invoiceno = 1;
```

All three conditions in the `WHERE` clause are focused on the table RetailInvoice.  You say that even if you change the where condition to this:

```
WHERE   RetailInvoice.BranchID = 2
        AND RetailInvoice.YearID = 1
        AND RetailInvoice.invoiceno = 1;
```

..that it still shows you rows where RetailInvoice.BranchID = 1.  Vaguely speaking, that shouldn't be possible, since your `WHERE` clause would specifically dictate that only rows with a BranchID of 2 be returned.  I say "vaguely speaking" because I don't have a lot of information to go on here, but in principle what you're saying seems nonsensical.

Something in the description of the problem doesn't add up to me.  This problem should not be related to the `LEFT JOIN`, since none of the `WHERE` conditions point to one of the tables included by `LEFT JOIN`.  In other words, the problem appears to be elsewhere.

> FYI, `LEFT JOIN` simply means "Show me the information from
>   RetalInvoice even if there are no matching rows in the
>   RetailInvoicePayment or Client tables."
>   As opposed to an `INNER JOIN`, which would only show you data where a matching row was present in all three tables.